# Using Haskell Graphviz Library

Tags: haskell, graphviz

If I have a DotNode with an UnknownAttribute called "consumes", how do I access it later to get the value of "consumes" that was set earlier on when constructing the graph?

I've tried going through the source code to find getter functions, but haven't found any.

Update : The following code works as a way to access the attributes.

```
consumes :: Attributes -> [TL.Text]
consumes = foldl f []
             where 
               f b a = case a of
                         UnkownAttribute "consumes" t -> b <> TL.words t
                         _ -> b <> []
```

which can be called by:

```
consumes (nodeAttributes n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions:

- [`nodeAttributes :: DotNode -> [Attribute]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.20.1.0/docs/Data-GraphViz-Types-Graph.html#t:DotNode)
- [`isSpecifiedCustom :: Text -> Attribute -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.20.1.0/docs/Data-GraphViz-Attributes-Complete.html#v:isSpecifiedCustom)
- [`customValue :: Attribute -> Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.20.1.0/docs/Data-GraphViz-Attributes-Complete.html#v:customValue)

You can combine them as follows:

```
getConsumes :: DotNode -> [Text]
getConsumes n = 
  map customValue 
    (filter (isSpecifiedCustom "consumes") 
      (nodeAttributes n))
```

You might want to consider what should happen if there are multiple "consumes" attributes on the same node. I've chosen to just return all values.

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. I've updated my question with a solution that I came up with as work around. Not sure if it performs any differently.